# Broadcasting Row and Column Vector in Eigen C++

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3, array-broadcasting

I have following Python Code written in [NumPy](https://numpy.org/):

```
> r = 3
> y, x = numpy.ogrid[-r : r + 1, -r : r + 1]
> mask = numpy.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
> mask

array([[4.24264, 3.60555, 3.16228, 3.00000, 3.16228, 3.60555, 4.24264],
       [3.60555, 2.82843, 2.23607, 2.00000, 2.23607, 2.82843, 3.60555],
       [3.16228, 2.23607, 1.41421, 1.00000, 1.41421, 2.23607, 3.16228],
       [3.00000, 2.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000, 2.00000, 3.00000],
       [3.16228, 2.23607, 1.41421, 1.00000, 1.41421, 2.23607, 3.16228],
       [3.60555, 2.82843, 2.23607, 2.00000, 2.23607, 2.82843, 3.60555],
       [4.24264, 3.60555, 3.16228, 3.00000, 3.16228, 3.60555, 4.24264]])
```

Now, I am making the mask in [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) where I need to broadcast row and column vector. Unfortunately, it is not allowed so I made the following workaround:

```
int len = 1 + 2 * r;
MatrixXf mask = MatrixXf::Zero(len, len);
ArrayXf squared_yx = ArrayXf::LinSpaced(len, -r, r).square();
mask = (mask.array().colwise() + squared_yx) + 
       (mask.array().rowwise() + squared_yx.transpose());
mask = mask.cwiseSqrt();
cout << "mask" << endl << mask << endl;

4.24264 3.60555 3.16228       3 3.16228 3.60555 4.24264
3.60555 2.82843 2.23607       2 2.23607 2.82843 3.60555
3.16228 2.23607 1.41421       1 1.41421 2.23607 3.16228
      3       2       1       0       1       2       3
3.16228 2.23607 1.41421       1 1.41421 2.23607 3.16228
3.60555 2.82843 2.23607       2 2.23607 2.82843 3.60555
4.24264 3.60555 3.16228       3 3.16228 3.60555 4.24264
```

It works. But I wonder if there is another and shorter way to do it. Therefore my question is **how to broadcast Row and Column Vector in Eigen C++**?

### System Info

| Tool | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Eigen | 3.3.7 |
| GCC | 9.4.0 |
| Ubuntu | 20.04.4 LTS |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest approach (as in: most readable), is replicate.

```
  int r = 3;
  int len = 1 + 2 * r;
  const auto& squared_yx = Eigen::ArrayXf::LinSpaced(len, -r, r).square();
  const auto& bcast = squared_yx.replicate(1, len);
  Eigen::MatrixXf mask = (bcast + bcast.transpose()).sqrt();
```

Note that what you do is numerically unstable (for large r) and the hypot function exists to work around these issues. So even your python code could be better:

```py
r = 3
y, x = numpy.ogrid[-r : r + 1, -r : r + 1]
mask = numpy.hypot(x, y)
```

To achieve the same in Eigen, do something like this:

```
  const auto& yx = Eigen::ArrayXf::LinSpaced(len, -r, r);
  const auto& bcast = yx.replicate(1, len);
  Eigen::MatrixXf mask = bcast.binaryExpr(bcast.transpose(),
      [](float x, float y) noexcept -> float {
          return std::hypot(x, y);
  });
```

Eigen's documentation on binaryExpr is currently broken, so this is hard to find.

To be fair, you will probably never run into stability issues in this particular case because you will run out of memory first. However, it'd still like to point this out because seeing a naive `sqrt(x**2 + y**2)` is always a bit of a red flag. Also, in Python hypot might still worth it from a performance point because it reduces the number of temporary memory allocations and function calls.

### BinaryExpr

The documentation on binaryExpr is missing, I assume because the parser has trouble with Eigen's C++ code. In any case, one can find it indirectly as [CwiseBinaryOp](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.3/classEigen_1_1CwiseBinaryOp.html) and similarly [CwiseUnaryOp](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.3/classEigen_1_1CwiseUnaryOp.html), [CwiseNullaryOp](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.3/classEigen_1_1CwiseNullaryOp.html) and [CwiseTernaryOp](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.3/classEigen_1_1CwiseTernaryOp.html).

The use looks a bit weird but is pretty simple. It takes a functor (either a struct with `operator()`, a function pointer, or a lambda) and applies this element-wise.

The unary operation makes this pretty clear. If `Eigen::Array.sin()` didn't exist, you could write this:
`array.unaryExpr([](double x) -> double { return std::sin(x); })` to achieve exactly the same effect.

The binary and ternary versions take one or two more Eigen expressions as the second and third argument to the function. That's what I did above. The nullary version is explained in the documentation [in its own chapter](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.3/TopicCustomizing_NullaryExpr.html).

### Use of auto

Eigen is correct to warn about auto but only in that you have to know what you do. It is important to realize that auto on an Eigen expression just keeps the expression around. It does not evaluate it into a vector or matrix.

This is fine and very useful if you want to compose a complex expression that would be hard to read when put in a single statement. In my code above, there are no temporary memory allocations and no floating point computations take place until the final expression is assigned to the matrix.

As long as the programmer knows that these are expressions and not final matrices, everything is fine.

I think the main take-away is that use of auto with Eigen should be limited to short-lived (as in: inside a single function) scalar expressions. Any coding style that uses auto for everything will quickly break or be hard to read with Eigen. But it *can* be used safely and make the code more readable in the process without sacrificing performance in the same way as evaluating into matrices would.

As for why I chose `const auto&` instead of `auto` or `const auto`: Mostly force of habit that is unrelated to the task at hand. I mostly do it for instances like this:

```
const Eigen::Vector& Foo::get_bar();

void quz(Foo& foo)
{
    const auto& bar = foo.get_bar();
}
```

Here, bar will remain a reference whereas auto would create a copy. If the return value is changed, everything stays valid.

```
Eigen::Vector Foo::get_bar();

void quz(Foo& foo)
{
    const auto& bar = foo.get_bar();
}
```

Now a copy is created anyway. But everything continues to work because assigning the return value to a const-reference extends the lifetime of the object. So this may look like a dangling pointer, but it is not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to [numpy.hypot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hypot.html). Luckily, the value of r is not so big. I appreciate your kind response. Can you please provide explanation for `binaryExpr`? [The documentation for Eigen 3.3.x can not find binaryExpr](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.3/). Finally, seeing `auto` keyword is making me nervous, because [Eigen says do not use the auto keywords with Eigen ... blah blah blah](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.2/TopicPitfalls.html)

Comment: @RaviJoshi I extended the answer

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I got it. The `BinaryExpr` is a new learning! Thanks for sharing. Declaring as a reference vs. declaring the object directly, i.e., auto& squared_yx vs. auto squared_yx. I assume both of these should be the same and handled already by Eigen carefully. I didn't see the first notion in their documentation. But do we really need to write, say, ArrayXf& squared_yx in Eigen? (Although I agree that it is a good practice and doesn't hurt anyone). What do you recommend?

Comment: @RaviJoshi You don't have to use const references. Normal auto is fine in this case. I only do it for consistency. But I'm probably overly pedantic. And I would only use if for expressions, not arrays and matrices. There it would invite issues w.r.t. move-constructions, and inplace updates

Comment: I see. Sorry I didn’t mean const reference. I meant auto& vs auto (same as Vector& vs Vector). Both of them should be same thing in case of Eigen??? *(Although it is a good practice to use declaring as reference)*

Comment: @RaviJoshi ```auto&``` or ```VectorXf&``` would be different and likely don't even compile. Mutable references do not get the same, lenient treatment as const references

Comment: I mean `auto& bcast = squared_yx.replicate(1, len);` and `auto bcast = squared_yx.replicate(1, len);`

Comment: @RaviJoshi ```auto& bcast = ...``` should not compile. l-value references must point to something "named".